# JTextField not focusing after popup dialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have the following

```
public boolean warning(String message){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getFrame(), message, "Error",
                                  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    textField.requestFocusInWindow();
    return false;
}
```

However `textField` does not get focussed after the dialog is closed. It happens on windows only but on linux it is ok.
I am confused why it does not work on windows.

`textField.requestFocusInWindow();` should be getting called after I press the OK button on the dialog.

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: By TextField DYM JTextField?  If so, please be accurate, if not, don't mix AWT & Swing components.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: a) So edit the title (and take more care in future).  b) Any chance of seeing that SSCCE?

Comment: request focus on the text field before you show the option pane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         textField.requestFocusInWindow();
     }
 });
```

Comment: One possibility could be that warning is called in the event thread handling some event, having difficulties with other event handling. invokeLater ensures that requestFocusInWindow will get handled (later). _Warning: that might be a misconception of me._